# Clean Hoverover Effect on Menu

Tags: html, css, less

Here's the site I'm working on:

http://kickstartyourbiz.info/

I've built it scratch from HTML so far, and it's on wordpress. As you can see, when you hover-over, there is an effect, but it looks horrible. I'd like it so the whole orange menu area around a particular link changes color. So it looks like more of a "block" than just a outlined piece of text.

For some reason, I'm having a hard time doing this, and I'm not sure why. Here's the code, any help is greatly appreciated:

HTML/PHP:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="container-non-responsive">
    <?php 
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
        'container-non-responsive' => '',
        'menu_class' => 'inline'
    )); 
    ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.main-nav {
width: 100%;
height: 66px;
background-color: @nav-bar;

ul {

    li {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        a {
            color: @nav-text;

            &:hover {
                background-color: #cb4800;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

NOTE: this CSS is without my hacked attempts to fix it. I tried adding some height to it, but it didn't balance well on the menu.

Any ideas on new directions I can try out would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is your CSS nested?

Comment: followed a tutorial that did this and it was much easier when adding each individual element. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Well, you aren't writing valid CSS if you are nesting your elements. It's possible that you were reading a tutorial on [tag:less].

Comment: Oh yeah, it is in LESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.  Remove the fixed height on the `main-nav`, then remove the top margin on the `li` and then add padding to the top and bottom of the `a`.

```
.main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 66px;  Remove */
  background-color: @nav-bar;

  ul {

    li {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 0; /* Add */
      a {
        color: @nav-text;
        display: block; /* Add */
        padding: 20px 0; /* Add */

        &:hover {
            background-color: #cb4800;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Any way to add a tiny bit of padding to the sides? If you see on current site, it's very close to the sides, but the top is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out. ;) Thanks again!

Comment: Great.  I was going to mention adding padding to sides, but some people aren't keen on the fact that the first link won't line up with the logo until it's hovered.  Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.main-nav {
width: 100%;
height: 66px;
background-color: @nav-bar;
}

ul li {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
       }
ul li a {
     color: @nav-text;
     }
ul li a:hover {
     background-color: #cb4800;
     text-decoration: none;
            }
```

worked in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrKt9/)

Comment: Isn't that what I have already, just taken out of nested? If you go to the site I linked in the main post, I currently have a hover-over effect like the one in that fiddle, but I want it to encompass the entire "orange bar" menu area, instead of the text by itself.

Comment: How the menu hover doesn't just go around the type, it's equally spaced on the top and sides

Answer (score 0):

Here'e a potential solution. The key with this approach, is to make the li element fill the entire height of the navbar. I've done that by using the line-height attribute of the navbar, rather than setting an absolute height on it, followed by a padding or margin to get the text to sit at the correct vertical position.

A potential down-fall is that the menu item will be highlighted but not necessarily clickable - since the mouse is hovering over the li element, but is not yet over the a element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hstB2/2/

**CSS:**

```
#navBar
{
    line-height: 66px;
    background-color: #ff831d;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
}
#navBar ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
#navBar ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

#navBar ul li:hover
{
    background-color: #cb4800;
}
#navBar ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='navBar'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>about us</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>clients</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```